# Can Protractor be used to connect to actual API?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

We are trying to build  an end-to-end testing mechanism for our angular Js project. Is it possible  for me to call an Actual API (Not mock) from protractor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do it. you can use `http` node module to make xmlhttprequest to the api and use the response in your test. Look at below example.

```
 var http = require('http');
 var options = {
        host: "www.yourdomain.com" ,
        path: "/api_url",
        port: 8888, //your application port number
    };
http.get(options,function(response) {
            var body = '';
            response.on('data', function(d) {
                body += d;
            });
            response.on('end', function() {
                try{
                    console.log(body)
                }catch (err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
            });

        }).on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```